# glDrawElements not rendering input from obj file

Tags: opengl, lisp, common-lisp, wavefront

I'm writing an object loader in lisp using cl-opengl, and when trying to render the loaded vertices/elements using `glDrawElements`, I'm left with a blank screen.

```
(require :cl-opengl)
(require :sdl2)

(defvar *vertices* nil)
(defvar *elements* nil)

(setf *vertices* (make-array 9 :fill-pointer 0))
(setf *elements* (make-array 9 :fill-pointer 0))

(defvar *vertex-shader* "
#version 330 core 
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);
}
")

(defvar *fragment-shader* "
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

void main() {
    FragColor = vec4(0.95f, 0.98f, 0.65f, 1.0f);
}
")

(defun split-str-1 (string &optional (separator " ") (r nil))
  (let ((n (position separator string
                     :from-end t
                     :test #'(lambda (x y)
                               (find y x :test #'string=)))))
    (if n
        (split-str-1 (subseq string 0 n) separator (cons (subseq string (1+ n)) r))
      (cons string r))))

(defun split-str (string &optional (separator " "))
  (split-str-1 string separator))

(defun parse-float (number)
  (with-input-from-string (in number)
    (read in)))

(defun load-obj (file-name)
   (let ((file (open file-name)))
     (with-open-stream (source file)
       (loop for line = (read-line source nil nil)
          while line do
            (let* ((split-line (split-str line " "))
                   (header (car split-line))
                   (rest (cdr split-line)))
              (cond ((string= header "v")
                     (dolist (vertex rest)
                       (vector-push-extend (parse-float vertex) vertices)))
                    ((string= header "f")
                     (dolist (face rest)
                       (let ((element (parse-integer (car (split-str face "/")))))
                          (vector-push-extend (- element 1) elements))))))))))

(defun main ()
  (load-obj "tortoise.obj")
  (sdl2:with-init (:everything)
  (sdl2:gl-set-attr :context-profile-mask 0)
  (sdl2:gl-set-attr :context-major-version 3)
  (sdl2:gl-set-attr :context-minor-version 3)

  (sdl2:with-window (win :flags `(:shown :opengl))
    (sdl2:with-gl-context (gl-context win)
    (sdl2:gl-make-current win gl-context)
    (gl:viewport 0 0 800 600)
    (gl:clear-color 0.957 0.376 0.286 1.0)

    (let ((glarray (gl:alloc-gl-array :float (length vertices)))
          (glarray-2 (gl:alloc-gl-array :unsigned-short (length elements))))
      (dotimes (i (length elements))
        (setf (gl:glaref glarray-2 i) (aref elements i)))
      (dotimes (i (length vertices))
        (setf (gl:glaref glarray i) (aref vertices i)))

      (let ((vbo (gl:gen-buffer))
            (vao (gl:gen-vertex-array))
            (ebo (gl:gen-buffer)))
        (gl:bind-vertex-array vao)
        (gl:bind-buffer :array-buffer vbo)
        (gl:buffer-data :array-buffer :static-draw glarray)
        (gl:free-gl-array glarray)
        (gl:bind-buffer :element-array-buffer ebo)
        (gl:buffer-data :element-array-buffer :static-draw glarray-2)
        (gl:vertex-attrib-pointer 0 4 :float nil 0 0)
        (gl:enable-vertex-attrib-array 0)

        (let ((vertex-shader (gl:create-shader :vertex-shader))
              (fragment-shader (gl:create-shader :fragment-shader)))
          (gl:shader-source vertex-shader *vertex-shader*)
          (gl:shader-source fragment-shader *fragment-shader*)
          (gl:compile-shader vertex-shader)
          (gl:compile-shader fragment-shader)
          (print (gl:get-shader-info-log vertex-shader))
          (print (gl:get-shader-info-log fragment-shader))

          (let ((program (gl:create-program)))
            (gl:attach-shader program vertex-shader)
            (gl:attach-shader program fragment-shader)
            (gl:link-program program)
            (gl:delete-shader vertex-shader)
            (gl:delete-shader fragment-shader)
            (gl:use-program program)))

        (sdl2:with-event-loop (:method :poll)
          (:idle ()
                 (gl:clear :color-buffer)
                 (gl:bind-vertex-array vao)
                 (gl:draw-elements :triangles glarray-2)
                 (gl:flush)
                 (sdl2:gl-swap-window win))
          (:quit () t))))))))
```

I've experimented with multiple obj files, and the results are the same; nothing is drawn to the screen. I've looked at some of the other SO posts and haven't found anything particularly helpful and can't really think of anything that would be causing this.

Comment: Do you get at least a coloured background? Next step is if you get some shaders error.

Comment: It would be useful to indent/format the code a bit better. I would also think that variables `vertices` and `elements` should be written as `*vertices*` and `*elements*`.

Comment: @Ripi2 Yeah, I get a colored background

Comment: @RainerJoswig Alright, fixed.

Comment: the DEFVAR / SETF combination is usually written as DEFPARAMETER.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case the `vertex` array is an array with coordinates of 3 components (x, y, z). So the "size" parameter of `gl:vertex-attrib-pointer` has to be 3 instead of 4:

```
(gl:vertex-attrib-pointer 0 3 :float nil 0 0)
```

Note, by using a size of 4, the specification of the vertex coordinates is misaligned. And at the end the vertex array is accessed out of bounds.

---

Your assumption about the indices of the *obj* file may be wrong.

In general a *obj* file looks like this:

```
v -1.000000 0.000000 1.000000
v 1.000000 0.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 0.000000 -1.000000

vt 0.000000 0.000000
vt 1.000000 0.000000
vt 0.000000 1.000000
vt 1.000000 1.000000

vn 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000

f 1/1/1 2/2/1 4/4/1
f 1/1/1 4/4/1 3/3/1
```

It consists of vertex coordinates (`v` with 3 components), texture coordinates (`vt` 2 components) and normal vectors (`vn` 3 components).
Further there are the faces (`f`). Each faces specifies a single triangle, with 3 vertex coordinates and its attributes.
Each vertex consists of three indices the 1st one is the index of the vertex coordinate, the 2nd one is the index of the texture coordinate and the 3d one is the index of the normal vector.

This meanse that the following face

```
f 1/1/1 2/2/1 4/4/1
```

defines a single triangle (with 3 vertices) where the indices of the vertex coordiantes (1st indices) are

```
1//   2//   4//
```

the indices of the coresponding texture coordinates (2nd indices) are

```
/1/   /2/   /4/
```

and the indices of the coresponding normal vectors (3rd indices) are

```
//1   //1   //1
```

---

You may try

```
vertices #(-0.707 -0.5 0.0 
            0.707 -0.5 0.0
            0.0    1.0 0.0)
```

instead of the orignal vertex array and

```
elements #(0 1 2)
```

instead of the orignal indices, to draw a single triangle, for debug reasons.

Comment: still, nothing is drawn

Comment: also, I'm relatively sure I'm parsing the obj files correctly, I double-checked the data inside the vectors and they matched up with what was in the obj file.

Comment: Yeah, they are. Here's the obj file I'm using https://pastebin.com/hEYjbGhp. Setting vertices/elements to what you had in your answer didn't draw anything

Comment: @PavelF Just wanted to point out that, from what i've read, the Indices in .obj files don't match up correctly, and are not out-of-the-box ready to be given to GL.DrawElements. You need to reorganize them. I'm still trying to figure out how to reorganize them.